# "Go snorkeling at" vs "Go snorkeling to"

Tags: prepositions

The question is:

**Where can we go snorkeling and scuba diving in Malaysia?**

Possible answers:

> 1. We can **go snorkeling** and scuba diving **to** the pleasant beach resorts in Malaysia.
> 2. We can **go snorkeling** and scuba diving **at** the pleasant beach resorts in Malaysia.

What preposition, **'to'** or **'at'**, I should choose?

Comment: It depends. If you're swimming all the way there, use *to the ... resorts*. If you're going there some other way, then swimming once you reach the destination, use *at the ... resorts*. If you're swimming inside the resorts (and not at the beaches nearby), use *in the ... resorts*.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

If you're travelling to the resorts before swimming, use *at*:

> We can go snorkeling and scuba diving **at** the pleasant beach resorts in Malaysia. We'll fly from Singapore to the resorts, stay for three days of water activities, then fly back.

If you're swimming inside the resorts and not at the beaches nearby, use *in* (this was part of the original question):

> We can go snorkeling and scuba diving **in** the pleasant beach resorts in Malaysia. The pools at the resorts have been specially booked for these activities. Please note that swimming in the ocean is prohibited for the duration of this trip.

If you're swimming all the way there, use *to*:

> We can go snorkeling and scuba diving **to** the pleasant beach resorts in Malaysia. We'll charter a boat and start our aquatic adventure an hour away from our respective resorts.

You can also use *to* if you're swimming intermittently on your way there. The usage is slightly different, though:

> We can go snorkeling and scuba diving all the way **to** the pleasant beach resorts in Malaysia. There will be five stops along the way for these water activities, but there will be no swimming once we arrive at the resorts.

Answer (score 0):

You can go snorkeling and scuba-diving
IN the ocean
AT a beach resort
IN Malaysia

You cannot go snorkeling and scuba-diving TO somewhere
unless it's just "to enjoy" the experience.